# Check password expiration or days to expire in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server (5.1.) using MySQL as my DB for users & roles. I with to use some password expiration check on authentication or at least to be able to query time for expiration or if had expired.

I have set these in repository/conf/identity/identity-mgt.properties:

```
Authentication.Policy.Enable=true

Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Exist=false 
Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Lock=false
Authentication.Policy.Check.OneTime.Password=false
Authentication.Policy.Check.Password.Expire=true

Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time=2
```

However, I can't get to use this. RemoteUserStoreManagerService / getPasswordExpirationTime always return -1. What should I configure or what API should I use to extract expiration true/false or when password will expire?

Answer (score 0):

These two properties had been introduced initially to `IS` planning to support password expiry, but the implementation was never done.

if `Authentication.Policy.Check.Password.Expire` is set to true, then the when the user updates the password, timestamp of password update is set as a user claim.

But `Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time` is not logically used anywhere in the code base, and ideally should be removed.

Anyways, you can achieve the same functionality in a different way using password policy authenticators in `IS`. Hope this helps